# crontab not working in Ubuntu

Tags: cron

I am working on Ubuntu 14.05 64 bit which is powered by Digitalocean.

and I tried to schedule a task for every 5 min using Crontab.

I did

```
crontab -e
```

and wrote like,

```
MAILTO=root
*/5 * * * * cd /root/ntry_selenium && /root/ntry_selenium/ladder288.sh 2>&1 |  mail -s "Cronjob ouput" root
```

and lastly,

```
service cron restart
```

I found how to redirect stdout and stderr on Internet and wrote as above, but nothing happened on /var/mail/root and console(I guess 2>&1 means redirect stderr to stdout, where stdout may be displayed on console).

the ladder288.sh file is:

```
#!/bin/sh
python /root/ntry_selenium/ladder288Fetch.py &
```

the ladder288Fetch.py file makes a txt file when it is run, but after I scheduled crontab, no txt file was generated since then.

I couldn't find any evidence that my crontab ever ran. What's wrong with this and what is the most secure way to leave stderr and stdout about crontab?

Comment: have you tried to run the very same command manually? Does it work as expected?

Comment: Yes, it works as expected.

Comment: cron does not have a console to redirect the output, though, so I expect that the pipe isn't working here.
Your best solution is to write a script that does everything by itself and call that script in cron